# How to 301 redirect domain2.com/subpage/ to domain1.com/subpage/?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Im changing the main domain on a website and currently have two domain names added as server alias.

For example this means that I can request http://**domain1**.com/subpage/ and http://**domain2**.com/subpage/ and get the same result - server is the same so it resolves to the same place.

**How do I 301 redirect http://domain2.com/subpage/ to http://domain1.com/subpage/?**

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've tried with the following, but that just makes the server "chrash"/makes it un-responsive

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^oldsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following for my use-case:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://newddomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at oldsite root directory `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So every things at oldsite will be directed to newsite with same sub folders or files

Comment: There is no old site - server for old and new site is the same and both old and new domain resolves to the same server. When I try with the above, the website becomes un-responsive

Comment: where did you put the above code ? i meant in which directory?

Comment: the root directory - posted my solution below - thanks for taking the time though!